# Ansible: Copy contents of a directory to a location

Tags: ansible

I'm willing to transfer the **contents** of a folder unzipped from a source say `myfolder` to a location say `dest_dir` but apparently everything I try moves/copies/generates `myfolder` in the `dest_dir` location.

I tried

```
command: mv src dest_dir
```

I also tried unarchiving in the `dest_dir` location using,

```
unarchive:
    src: /path/to/myfolder
    dest: dest_dir
    copy: no
  become: yes
```

Apparently, for `copy` module, I found that `remote_src` does not support recursive copying yet.

What is the correct way to go about this?

Normally, in my system, I would do `mv /path/to/myfolder/* dest_dir` but wildcards throw an error with Ansible.

I'm using Ansible 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do it easily in Ansible is because Ansible was not designed to do it.

Just execute the command directly with `shell` module. Your requirement is not idempotent anyway:

```
- shell: mv /path/to/myfolder/* dest_dir
  become: yes
```

Pay attention to `mv` defaults, you might want to add `-f` to prevent it from prompting for confirmation.

---

Otherwise play with `synchronize` module, but there's no value added for "move" operation. Just complexity.